# Duplicate entries in file

Tags: shell, grep

I have a file with content as below,

```
123 ABC
12345 ABC-test
```

In the shell script, I need an exact entry instead of two duplicate results, but unable to get the exact entry.
For example:
`grep "ABC"`
returns both the entries, but I want a specific entry, i.e., if I search for "ABC", I should get only "123 ABC" and not the other entry.

Comment: If you can handle awk: `awk '$2=="ABC"' file`

Answer (score 1):

Since you consider words to be whitespace-separated chunks, it is easier to use `awk` here since it reads lines (records) and splits them into fields (non-whitespace chunks) by default:

```sh
awk '$2=="ABC"' file > newfile
awk '/([[:space:]]|^)ABC([[:space:]]|$)/' file > newfile
```

Here, the first `awk` will output all lines where the second word is `ABC`. The second `awk` outputs all lines with `ABC` followed/preceded with a whitespace or at start/end of the line.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/EqnY29):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='123 ABC
12345 ABC-test'
awk '$2=="ABC"' <<< "$s"
awk '/([[:space:]]|^)ABC([[:space:]]|$)/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
123 ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to forge proper regex (regular expression) - in this case you want only those lines, where ABC is not surrounded by other characters (is on boundaries):

```
grep -e '\bABC\b'
```

should do the work. `-e` switch enables extended regular expressions in grep. Check also some regex tutorials, i.e. https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.